# change tableview to view in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

i'm having a tableview nib file.(contains a list)

i want to add some buttons with it
so i want to change the tableview to view and put the tableview inside that view
then add buttons to the view..

what to change in the class files and how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the tableview to view, you can do in the IBOutlet.

By changing the value in the Inspector Identity from UITableView to view. So that it will change to view and you can add buttons and some to that view.

or else you can add the buttons with out changing the IBOutlet with code.

you can change the UITableView frame and you can add buttons to the view.

Regards,

Satya